# проблема с репозиториями (и yum) centos 6.3

Tags: centos, yum

Здравствуйте. Подскажите в чем проблема и в какую сторону копать)
Гугленье не помогает
Кажется проблема в старых репозиториях и в чем-то еще..
На вдс установлена CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

```
[root]# yum -y install munin munin-node
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&ar                                                                                                             ch=x86_64 error was
14: problem making ssl connection
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge er                                                                                                             ror was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge-ex                                                                                                             tras error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/mirrors-rpmforge-te                                                                                                             sting error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * remi: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-safe: remi.schlundtech.de
 * rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge-testing: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
remi                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi/primary_db                                          | 1.7 MB     00:00
remi-safe                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                     | 721 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge-extras                                          | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge-testing                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package munin.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(URI::_server) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(URI) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Taint::Runtime) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.                                                                                                             noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RRDs) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Params::Validate) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el                                                                                                             6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Server::Fork) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.e                                                                                                             l6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Server) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noa                                                                                                             rch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::SSLeay) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noa                                                                                                             rch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::SNMP) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarc                                                                                                             h
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::CIDR) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarc                                                                                                             h
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Munin::Common::Timeout) for package: munin-2.0.2                                                                                                             0-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Munin::Common::TLSClient) for package: munin-2.0                                                                                                             .20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Munin::Common::Defaults) for package: munin-2.0.                                                                                                             20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Munin::Common::Config) for package: munin-2.0.20                                                                                                             -1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Log::Log4perl) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.n                                                                                                             oarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Socket::INET6) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.e                                                                                                             l6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTML::Template) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.                                                                                                             noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Copy::Recursive) for package: munin-2.0.20                                                                                                             -1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(FCGI) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::SHA1) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Date::Manip) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noa                                                                                                             rch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Crypt::DES) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noar                                                                                                             ch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Carp::Always) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Cache::Memcached) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el                                                                                                             6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Cache::Cache) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI::Fast) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarc                                                                                                             h
--> Processing Dependency: perl(CGI::Carp) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarc                                                                                                             h
---> Package munin-node.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::Parser) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el                                                                                                             6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::LibXML) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el                                                                                                             6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::DNS) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.n                                                                                                             oarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(List::MoreUtils) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-                                                                                                             1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(LWP::UserAgent) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1                                                                                                             .el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(LWP::Simple) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el                                                                                                             6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBD::Pg) for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
--> Processing Dependency: hdparm for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package munin.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
---> Package munin-common.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package munin-node.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: hdparm for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-CGI.noarch 0:3.49-2.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-Cache-Cache.noarch 0:1.06-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IPC::ShareLite) for package: perl-Cache-Cache-1.                                                                                                             06-2.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Cache-Memcached.noarch 0:1.29-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(String::CRC32) for package: perl-Cache-Memcached                                                                                                             -1.29-1.el6.rfx.noarch
---> Package perl-Carp-Always.noarch 0:0.09-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Crypt-DES.x86_64 0:2.05-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-Pg.x86_64 0:2.17.1-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1.el6.rfx.                                                                                                             x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1                                                                                                             .el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-Date-Manip.noarch 0:5.56-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-DateTime.x86_64 0:0.5300-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::Locale) >= 0.41 for package: perl-Date                                                                                                             Time-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::TimeZone) >= 0.59 for package: perl-Da                                                                                                             teTime-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-Digest-SHA1.x86_64 0:2.13-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-FCGI.x86_64 1:0.71-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-File-Copy-Recursive.noarch 0:0.38-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-HTML-Template.noarch 0:2.9-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-IO-Socket-INET6.noarch 0:2.57-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket6) >= 0.12 for package: perl-IO-Socket-INE                                                                                                             T6-2.57-2.el6.rfx.noarch
---> Package perl-List-MoreUtils.x86_64 0:0.25.2-1.el6.test will be installed
---> Package perl-Log-Log4perl.noarch 0:1.30-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Log::Dispatch::FileRotate) >= 1.10 for package:                                                                                                              perl-Log-Log4perl-1.30-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::DOM) for package: perl-Log-Log4perl-1.30-1.                                                                                                             el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Log::Dispatch::Syslog) for package: perl-Log-Log                                                                                                             4perl-1.30-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Log::Dispatch::Screen) for package: perl-Log-Log                                                                                                             4perl-1.30-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Log::Dispatch::File) for package: perl-Log-Log4p                                                                                                             erl-1.30-1.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-CIDR.noarch 0:0.14-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Net-DNS.x86_64 0:0.71-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC_MD5) for package: perl-Net-DNS-0.71                                                                                                             -1.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-Net-SNMP.noarch 0:5.2.0-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4                                                                                                             .el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-SSLeay.x86_64 0:1.36-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-Net-Server.noarch 0:0.99-1.el6.rf will be installed
---> Package perl-Params-Validate.x86_64 0:0.95-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Test::More) for package: perl-Params-Validate-0.                                                                                                             95-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-Taint-Runtime.x86_64 0:0.03-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-URI.noarch 0:1.60-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-XML-LibXML.x86_64 0:1.70-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::SAX) >= 0.11 for package: perl-XML-LibXML-1                                                                                                             .70-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::NamespaceSupport) >= 1.07 for package: perl                                                                                                             -XML-LibXML-1.70-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-XML-Parser.x86_64 0:2.40-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-libwww-perl.noarch 0:5.837-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTML::Parser) >= 3.33 for package: perl-libwww-p                                                                                                             erl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) for package: perl-libwww-pe                                                                                                             rl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Crypt::SSLeay) for package: perl-libwww-perl-5.8                                                                                                             37-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) for package: perl-libwww                                                                                                             -perl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Gzip) for package: perl-libwww-per                                                                                                             l-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Uncompress::Inflate) for package: perl-libww                                                                                                             w-perl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Compress::Deflate) for package: perl-libwww-                                                                                                             perl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IO::Uncompress::RawInflate) for package: perl-li                                                                                                             bwww-perl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch
---> Package perl-rrdtool.x86_64 0:1.4.7-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rrdtool = 1.4.7 for package: perl-rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6                                                                                                             .rfx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: librrd.so.4()(64bit) for package: perl-rrdtool-1.4.7-                                                                                                             1.el6.rfx.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package munin.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
---> Package munin-node.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: hdparm for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 0:2.052-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-Pg.x86_64 0:2.17.1-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1.el6.rfx.                                                                                                             x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1                                                                                                             .el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-DateTime.x86_64 0:0.5300-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::Locale) >= 0.41 for package: perl-Date                                                                                                             Time-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DateTime::TimeZone) >= 0.59 for package: perl-Da                                                                                                             teTime-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-HTML-Parser.x86_64 0:3.69-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(HTML::Tagset) >= 3 for package: perl-HTML-Parser                                                                                                             -3.69-1.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.052-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) = 2.052 for package: perl-                                                                                                             IO-Compress-2.052-1.el6.rfx.noarch
---> Package perl-IPC-ShareLite.x86_64 0:0.17-1.el6.rf will be installed
---> Package perl-Log-Dispatch.noarch 0:2.27-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mail::Sender) for package: perl-Log-Dispatch-2.2                                                                                                             7-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Mail::Send) for package: perl-Log-Dispatch-2.27-                                                                                                             1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(MIME::Lite) for package: perl-Log-Dispatch-2.27-                                                                                                             1.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Log-Dispatch-FileRotate.noarch 0:1.19-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Net-DNS.x86_64 0:0.71-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC_MD5) for package: perl-Net-DNS-0.71                                                                                                             -1.el6.rfx.x86_64
---> Package perl-Net-SNMP.noarch 0:5.2.0-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4                                                                                                             .el6.noarch
---> Package perl-Socket6.x86_64 0:0.23-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-String-CRC32.x86_64 0:1.4-1.el6.rfx will be installed
---> Package perl-Test-Simple.noarch 0:0.98-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Test::Harness) >= 2.03 for package: perl-Test-Si                                                                                                             mple-0.98-1.el6.rfx.noarch
---> Package perl-XML-DOM.noarch 0:1.44-2.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(XML::RegExp) for package: perl-XML-DOM-1.44-2.el                                                                                                             6.rfx.noarch

тут вырежем, все не влазит

--> Running transaction check
---> Package munin.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Digest::HMAC) for package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.no                                                                                                             arch
---> Package munin-node.noarch 0:2.0.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: hdparm for package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch
---> Package perl-DBD-Pg.x86_64 0:2.17.1-1.el6.rfx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1.el6.rfx.                                                                                                             x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1                                                                                                             .el6.rfx.x86_64

тут вырежем, все не влазит

--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Net-SNMP-5.2.0-4.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Digest::HMAC)
Error: Package: rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: ruby
Error: Package: rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: libdbi.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: gettext
Error: Package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: postgresql
Error: Package: perl-Net-DNS-0.71-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: perl(Digest::HMAC_MD5)
Error: Package: perl-DBD-Pg-2.17.1-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: libpq.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-libwww-perl-5.837-2.el6.rfx.noarch (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: perl(Crypt::SSLeay)
Error: Package: rrdtool-1.4.7-1.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
Error: Package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: hdparm
Error: Package: perl-DateTime-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: perl(DateTime::Locale) >= 0.41
Error: Package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: sysstat
Error: Package: munin-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Digest::HMAC)
Error: Package: munin-node-2.0.20-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: sysstat
Error: Package: perl-DateTime-0.5300-2.el6.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: perl(DateTime::TimeZone) >= 0.59
Error: Package: perl-MailTools-2.12-1.el6.rfx.noarch (rpmforge-extras)
           Requires: perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Гуглится такое: http://avz.org.ua/wp/2015/02/25/yum-errno-14-problem-making-ssl-connection/

Comment: не помогло ((((

Comment: слишком много репозиториев разных, убери rpmforge-extras
у тебя происходит конфликт зависимостей,
какай-то прога из epel требует библиотеку, а она в rpmforge-extras ...